# How to passing variable containing spaces to hive?

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to send a complete select statement to my hive script via a variable via shell script like

```
QUERY="select * from abc;"
hive -f hive_script.hql -hivevar QUERY=${QUERY}
```

My hive script is as below:

```
CREATE table AS ${QUERY}
```

However this gives me an error. I checked the hive log and the query turns out as

```
 CREATE table AS select
```

, i.e. it ignores the `* from abc;` part
How do I pass a variable with spaces in it to my hive script?

Comment: what is version of hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have a very good explanation

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Essentially you need to put double quotes between your variable like this to preserve multiple values

```
QUERY="select * from abc;"
hive -f hive_script.hql -hivevar QUERY="${QUERY}"
```